# Remove video noise from video with ffmpeg without producing blur / scale down effect

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, video-processing, noise, noise-reduction

My videos are 1920x1080 recorded with high ISO (3200) using smartphone (to get bright view, backlight scene mode). It produce a lot of noise. I try many video filter but all of them produce blur similar to when we reduce the resolution in half then increase it back again.

Is there a good video noise filter that only remove noise without producing blur?

Because if it produce blur, I would prefer to not do any filtering at all.

I have tried video filter:

- nlmeans=s=30:r=3:p=1
- vaguedenoiser=threshold=22:percent=100:nsteps=4
- owdenoise=8:6:6
- hqdn3d=100:0:50:0
- bm3d=sigma=30:block=4:bstep=8:group=1:range=8:mstep=64:thmse=0:hdthr=5:estim=basic:planes=1
- dctdnoiz=sigma=30:n=4
- fftdnoiz=30:1:6:0.8

All produce blur, some even worse. I have to use strong setting to make the noise moderately removed. I end up halving the resolution and use remove grain then scale it up again. This is much better for me than all the above method (pp filter is used to reduce size without reducing image detail):

- scale=960:540,removegrain=3:0:0:0,pp=dr/fq|8,scale=1920:1080

code example

`FOR %%G IN (*.jpg) DO "ffmpeg.exe" -y -i "%%G"  -vf "nlmeans=s=30:r=3:p=1" -qmin 1 -qmax 1 -q:v 1   "%%G.jpg"`

[Part of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF7ID.jpg)
`The image:`

Answer (score 0):

To help with blur, I always use unsharp to sharpen the image after nlmeans.  Below are the parameters I find work best on old grainy movies, or 4K transfers of old movies that create unacceptable grain.  It seems to work quite well.  For 4K movies, it almost makes them as good as the 1080p Blu Ray versions.

nlmeans=s=1:p=7:pc=5:r=3:p=3
unsharp=7:7:2.5

Comment: thanks for the answer. I think you should try my method too and compare, because I think nlmeans is eliminating detail instead of noise.

Comment: I wonder if there are smart smoother for ffmpeg:
https://www.rationalqm.us/hiq/smoothhiq.html

Comment: Hi Sucahyo, I will try that and compare the results.

Comment: ok, I will look forward for the result.

Comment: The final nlmeans filter option should be "rc=3" rather than a duplicate 'p'.